# MS Access 'error 9 subscript out of range' saving an Excel workbook with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, remote-desktop

I have an Access database split into a front and back-end, still using the mdb file format as user level security is required.  Part of the db functionality is to create reports in Excel (via VBA).  One of my routines uses a blank excel workbook as a template and copies it to paste the report data into. Users in the office have MS Office 365 on their desktop machines and each user has their own copy of the front-end database.  The back end database sits on a server.  These users have always been able to run this report and when I recently gave them an updated copy of the front-end they could still run this report.  There was no change to the code that creates this report in the updated front-end database.

However there are some remote users on RDS.  They were using a previous version of Office and this report worked.  They were updated to Office 365 and the report worked.  I gave them the updated front-end and they could not run the report.  Below is the code:

```
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Dim objReportDataWrkbk As Excel.Workbook

'open Excel
On Error Resume Next
'Try first to use an existing instance.
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then
    'Excel wasnt running
     Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo Err_ExportExternalReferralDataToExcel
    
'copy Excel template
objExcel.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 5
Set objReportDataWrkbk = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(strPathToExportTemplateFiles & strTemplateName)
objReportDataWrkbk.SaveAs strPathToTempExportFolder & strFileName
```

For RDS users the SaveAs line throws the error 'Error 9 subscript out of range'

I have stepped through the code and the part that starts Excel works - I can see Excel open.
The line that copies the workbook works - I can see the workbook open in Excel.
It hits the SaveAs line and I get my error.

I have done a Debug.Print of strPathToTempExportFolder & strFileName - and the path is valid and the file name is not something odd that may prompt an error.
I have tried modifying strPathToTempExportFolder to save in another location and I still get the error.
I am told by the office IT that the users have relevant network permissions to copy files and save files in the locations I have been trying.
Is there something blindingly obvious that I am missing here.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `strPathToTempExportFolder & strFileName`  where in the code are these variables set?

Comment: There is definately a path separator between the folder path and the file name.

Comment: strPathToTempExportFolder & strFileName are set outside of this routine.  When I first got the error I put in the line Debug.Print strPathToTempExportFolder & strFileName before the save line to check what the variables held and they held a valid path and file name.

Comment: That error message doesn't seem like it would be thrown by that line.  Do you have any event code which would be triggered by a save?  Set your VBA error handling to "Break in class module", comment out the `On Error GoTo Err_ExportExternalReferralDataToExcel` and then see if that changes anything.

Comment: Agree it is an unlikely message for that line.  I will try your suggestion, but can't do now until Monday.  Thanks.

Comment: @Tim-williams I followed your suggestion - there is no event code that is triggered by the save.  I amended the SaveAs to SaveCopyAs and this did not generate an error.  Not understanding why one method works and not the other.

Comment: So what exactly happens when the error handling is commented out and you get the error?  Do you get a "Debug" button?  Does anything change if you make sure Excel is visible after opening it?

Comment: @tim-williams the code went on to the next line and began writing the data into the workbook.  (The on error resume next is still in there above the lines to open Excel.)  There was no 'Debug' button.  The file it copied is called ExportTemplateAnon and Excel was writing the data into a file called ExportTemplateAnon1.  This is not the file name specified by strTemplateName and it was in the Documents folder which is not the folder specified by strPathToExportTemplateFiles.

Comment: Have not found cause for this error, so have used SaveAsCopy after writing data to the spreadsheet and saving in the location strPathToTempExportFolder & strFileName - this did not cause an error.